# Prove that $(-a).b=-(a.b)$ , $(-a)^{-1}=-(a^{-1})$ and $(a.b)^{-1}=a^{-1}.b^{-1}$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

> Prove that
>
> 1)$\forall a, b \in \mathbb{R}$, $(-a).b=-(a.b)$.

$(-a).b=(-a).b+0$

$=(-a).b+[a.b+(-(a.b))]$

$=[(-a).b+a.b]+(-(a.b))$

$=[((-a)+a)b]+(-(a.b))$

$=0.b+(-(a.b))$

$=0+(-(a.b))$

$=-(a.b)$

> 2) $\forall a\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \lbrace 0\rbrace, (-a)^{-1}=-(a^{-1})$.

$(-a)^{-1}=(-a)^{-1}.1$

$=(-a)^{-1}.[(-a).(-a^{-1})]$

$=[(-a)^{-1}.(-a)].(-a^{-1})$

$=1.(-a^{-1})$

$=-a^{-1}$

> 3) If $a\neq 0$ and $b \neq 0$, then $ab \neq 0$ and $(a.b)^{-1}=a^{-1}.b^{-1}$.

$(a.b)^{-1}=(a.b)^{-1}.1$

$=(a.b)^{-1}.[a.b.b^{-1}.a^{-1}]$

$=(a.b)^{-1}.[(a.b).(b^{-1}.a^{-1})]$

$=[(a.b)^{-1}.(a.b)].(b^{-1}.a^{-1})$

$=1.(b^{-1}.a^{-1})$

$=b^{-1}.a^{-1}$

$=a^{-1}.b^{-1}$

Is that true please? Thanks.

I used these axioms:

[image]

Comment: For 1) you first have to prove that $0.b = 0$ which usually is *not* a given.

Comment: In 2) you have no reason to assume $(-a)(-a^{-1}) = 1$.  Unless you are assuming $(-a)(-b) = ab$ and so $(-a)(-a^{-1}) = a.a^{-1} = 1$.  If so you should point that out, it wasn't clear.  ANd to you *do* need to prove that $(-a)(-b) = ab$.  It's not a given.

Comment: 3)  Is $.$ commutative?  Was that an axiom? it isn't true if $.$ isn't commutative.  So perhaps before either of had even gotten started I should have asked?  What exactly are you doing?  Is $.$ supposed to be multiplication on the reals? The rationals? An arbitrary field?  What class is this for?  What are your axioms?  Are you just assuming the field axioms, etc?  Or is this high school algebra?  Or elementary school arithmetic?  Context does matter.

Comment: Lest I seem too critical.  Yes, your proofs and reasoning are perfectly correct and the way to go.  But you must prove $0.b = 0$ for all $b$ and that $(-a)(-b) = ab$.

Comment: Thank you so much prof, I used the 9 axioms [in the question]. For $0.b=b$ my prof was prof if, I will prove that $(-a)(-b)=ab$,

Comment: For this kind of proof, I'll recommend you write down which axiom/reason you use on each line (e,g  for the line 0.b = b, you can  say your prof has prove it in the class) This will minimize the chance to have any logic gap in your deduction.

Comment: Why did you post the image sideways?  So that it would be more difficult for us to read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proofs are mostly good.

But before you can prove 1) you must prove:

> $0\cdot b = 0$ for all $b$.

Pf:  $0\cdot b = (0 + 0)\cdot b$ (as $0 = 0 + 0$)$

$= 0\cdot b + 0\cdot b$ (via distribution)

So $0 = 0\cdot b + (-0\cdot b) $ (as every number has an additive inverse)

$= (0\cdot b + 0\cdot b) + (-0\cdot b) $ (by substitution)

$= 0\cdot b + (0\cdot b + (-0\cdot b))$ (associativity)

$= 0\cdot b + 0$ (definition of inverse)

$= 0\cdot b$ (definition of 0)$

In your prove of 2) you substituted $1$ with $(-a)(-a^{-1})$ which I don't think is justified without proof.

But you have proven in 1) that $(-a)(-a^{-1}) = -(a(-a^{-1}))$ and by commutativity $-(a(-a^{-1})) = -((-a^{-1})a)$ and by 1 again $= -(-(a^{-1}a)) = -(-1)$.

But we still need to prove that $-(-a) = a$ which can be done as

$-(-a) + (-a) =0$

$-(-a) + (-a) + a  = 0 + a$

$-(-a) + 0 = a$

$-(-a) = a$.

Your 3) is just fine

Answer (score 2):

Why not: $(-a)b + ab = (-a + a)b= 0\cdot b = 0$ (assuming you know the latter, which si not an axiom but a consequence of them, hopefully shown before), so that $ab$ is the additive inverse of $(-a)b$ and as inverses are unique in any group we have $(-a)b = -(ab)$.

For the second $a\cdot a^{-1}=1$ by definition. Assuming you have shown $(-x)\cdot(-y)=xy$ we write $(-a) \cdot -(a^{-1})=1$ and so $-(a^{-1})$ is the multiplicative inverse of $-a$ so by unicity again $(-a)^{-1} = -(a^{-1})$.

For 3, $(ab)(a^{-1}b^{-1}) =1 $ by applying commutativity and the definition of inverse twice. So again by unicity of multiplicative inverses: $(ab)^{-1} = a^{-1} \cdot b^{-1}$.

So as a basic algebra lemma for all of this: if $(G, \ast,^{-1}, e)$ is a group, inverses are unique: if $a \ast b=e$ then $b=a^{-1}$, where $a^{-1}$ is promised by the group axioms. In a field $F$, $(F, + ,-,0)$ forms a group and so does $(F\setminus \{0\},\cdot,^{-1}, 1)$, so we can apply this.

Comment: "Why not: (−a)b+ab=(−a+a)b=0⋅b=0"  Well..... if one is *REALLY* picky one can point out that we know $-(ab)$ exists but *not* that it is unique.  So $-(ab) + ab = 0$ and $(-a)b + ab = 0$ doesn't actually mean that $-(ab) = (-a)b$ until you con prove it.  But that's pretty picky.....

Comment: @fleablood as remarked, in a group all inverses are unique (pretty easy lemma). And the OP also needs to show $0x=0$ which follows from unicity of the unit element in a group etc.